# how to turn array items --> into individual Objects --> and place them into array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am fetching an array of Ids from from an API.

.... I want to convert **Each Id** in the array Into and Object

Ex **{   id: '1'  }**

**then** create just 1  array with all the kew:value pairs inside.

(look at the **RESULT DESIRED** at the end)

so far I got this

```
let ids = ['1', '2']
let obj = { id: '' }

ids.map(element => {
    obj.id = element
    console.log(obj);
   });
```

{ id: '1'} {id: '2'}

How can I put that in a Variable that the result looks like this:

**RESULT DESIRED**

```
      [
        { id: '1'},
        { id: '2'}
       ]
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
let arr = ["1", '2']

const newArr = arr.map(element => {
  return {id: element}
});

console.log(newArr)
```

Comment: Wooow I've been trying this for an hour and didin't think about that!! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Well you seem to be almost there.

```js
const arr = ["1", "2"]

const objects = arr.map((id) => ({ id }))
console.log(objects)
```

[Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/map) returns an array of each element returned by the function it receives as argument. So all you need to do is assign this array to a variable and output it.

Comment: You need to move the round brackets thus: objects = arr.map(id => ({ id }))

Comment: Wooow I've been trying this for an hour and didin't think about that!! Thank you so much!